# Valgrind and containerized ASP.NET Core 7 - How to use it on my production env?

Tags: asp.net-core, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have an API with a leak that only reproducible on AKS. After exhausting a lot of other tools, I got a suggestion to use Valgrind. The problem is that Valgrind has to launch the process and the report is outputted after it terminates. On a regular AKS pod, I can't get the file out between the main command terminating and the pod restarting (to a blank state).

My AKS cluster doesn't have a persistent volume also, so, tough luck for me...

The lucky part here is that I don't need any actual traffic or a lot of time to get the leak. One request and 10 minutes should be enough.

How can I move forward?

Comment: Never heard of AKS. Valgrind has ways to output leak reports at any time, using client requests. These can be compiled into the exe or triggered using vgdb.